# Would this linked list be considered clean if written in an hour-long interview?

Tags: c++, linked-list

If you were interviewing me, and saw this code written in a little under an hour, would you consider me as a candidate for a position at your company if you knew I had 2 years of C++ experience?

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <cassert>

/*! \class Node to be used in likned list like constructors
 */
template <typename T>
class node 
{
private:
  T data;
  node * next;

public:
  /*! \brief Default constructor
   * Initialize next pointer to NULL and let data's default constructor
   * be called
   */
  node() :
    next(NULL)
  {}

  /*! \brief Parametered constructor
   * Initialize next pointer to NULL and set data to t
   */
  node(T t) :
    data(t),
    next(NULL)
  {}

  /*! \brief Copy constructor
   */
  node(const node & other) :
    data(other.data),
    next(other.next)
  {}

  /*! \brief Destructor
   */
  ~node() 
  {}

  /*! \brief Assignment operator
   */
  node & operator=(const node &other) 
  {
    data = other.data;
    next = other.next;

    return (*this);
  }

  /*! \brief Set the next pointer
   */
  void set_next(node *next_node) 
  {
    next = next_node;
  }

  /*! \brief Set the nodes data
   */  
  void set_data(T t) 
  {
    data = t;
  }

  /*! \brief Get the nodes data
   */    
  T get_data() {
    return data;
  }

  /*! \brief Get the nodes next pointer
   */      
  node * get_next() 
  {
    return next;
  }

  /*! \brief Equivalence operator
   */ 
  bool operator==(const node &other) 
  {
    return (data == other.data && next == other.next);
  }

  /*! \brief Not equivalence operator
   */   
  bool operator!=(const node &other) 
  {
    return (data != other.data || next != other.next);
  }
};

/*! \class Linked List
 */
template <typename T>
class linked_list
{
private:
  node<T> * head;

public:
  /*! \brief Default constructor
   * Initialize head pointer to NULL
   */
  linked_list() : 
    head(NULL) 
  {}

  /*! \brief Parametered constructor
   * Initialize head to a node
   */
  linked_list(node<T> &n) : 
    head(&n) 
  {}

  /*! \brief Copy constructor
   */
  linked_list(const linked_list & other) :
    head(other.head)
  {}

  /*! \brief Destructor
   */
  ~linked_list() 
  {}

  /*! \brief Assignment operator
   */
  linked_list & operator=(const linked_list &other) 
  {
    head = other.head;

    return (*this);
  }

  /*! \brief Get the head node pointer
   */      
  node<int> * get_head() 
  {
    return head;
  }

  /*! \brief Equivalence operator
   */ 
  bool operator==(const linked_list &other) 
  {
    return (head == other.head);
  }

  /*! \brief Not equivalence operator
   */   
  bool operator!=(const linked_list &other) 
  {
    return (head != other.head);
  }
};

void unit_test_linked_list()
{
  // Default constructor
  linked_list<int> l0;
  assert(!l0.get_head());

  // Parametered constructor
  node<int> n(5);
  linked_list<int> l1(n);
  assert(l1.get_head()->get_data() == 5);

  // Copy construtor
  linked_list<int> l2(l1);
  assert(l2 == l1);

  // Assignment and equivalence
  l0 = l2;
  assert(l2 == l1);
  assert(l2 == l0);
  assert(l1 == l0);
}

void unit_test_node()
{
  // Default constructor
  node<int> n;
  assert(!n.get_next());

  // Parameterd constructor and assignment operator
  n = node<int>(5);
  assert(!n.get_next() && n.get_data() == 5);

  // Copy constructor equivalence operator and not equivalent operator
  node<int> m(n);
  assert(n.get_data() == m.get_data() && n.get_next() == m.get_next());
  assert(!(m != n) && m == n);

  // Setters and getters
  m.set_data(6);
  m.set_next(&n);
  assert(m.get_data() == 6 && m.get_next()->get_data() == 5);
  assert(m.get_next()->get_next() == NULL);
}

int main() 
{
  unit_test_node();
  unit_test_linked_list();
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I can't speak for others, but I'd personally have some reservations. To be fair, perhaps I'm not being lenient enough for doing this under pressure in an hour, but there are multiple issues that I'd want to address with this code.

### Questions and Small Problems

Why is `node` not an internal class of `linked_list`? Generally, the user should neither know nor care about exactly how a `node` is represented. I'd let this slide pretty easily though, because it's a small oversight and can be fairly easily corrected.

You're not passing to your `node` constructor by `const T&` which I would have expected. If this is constructing from a type that is expensive to copy construct, this adds quite a bit of overhead.

Usage of `NULL` vs `nullptr`. Not a big deal, but it'd make me push you a little bit on knowledge of `C++11` constructs.

### Pain Points

The interface for your list is (somewhat) setup, but the implementation is very, very incomplete. As it currently stands, it doesn't really represent a list at all, but something that holds the address of a single element that exists outside the list, and is therefore tied to the lifetime of that object (which is a big, big problem).

Your `linked_list` constructor takes a `node<T>` as a parameter. This goes back to the first point about `node` being internal, but here it is more serious in my mind. This shows that you **do** expect the user to know/care about the `node` type. It also takes it by reference, and then simply makes the `head` node point to that address. This is all a bit worrying. It should be taking an element of type `T`, which it then wraps up in a `node`, and that is stored as the head element:

```
linked_list(const T& initial)
  : head(new node(initial))
{ }
```

You never `new` or `delete` anything - a `linked_list` that uses absolutely no dynamic storage is very strange indeed. It'd certainly make me want to press you on things like object lifetimes, stack and heap allocation, dangling references and the like.

There is no way to modify a list once it is created; something as basic as adding an element isn't possible. Even if these functions weren't finished in time, I'd expect just the declarations to be there, something like:

```
void push_front(const T& data)
{ }
```

Because of the lack of dynamic allocation, your copy constructor and assignment operator don't really do anything, and you don't have a destructor. Implementations of these would be something I'd heavily scrutinize. For a start, do they do what they are supposed to do? A copy constructor should be doing a **deep copy** of the list it is passed - many people get this wrong and end up simply doing a shallow copy, which generally means pointers pointing to deleted memory, and undefined behaviour.

`operator=` should either be using the *copy-swap* idiom or at least doing basic checks like `(this != &rhs)`, clearing the current data in the list, and copying the data from what is passed in as the argument to `operator=`. With your current implementation, none of this can be demonstrated properly.

Why is `get_head` declared as `node<int> *`? Why are you returning a `node` instead of simply returning the data? This should have two overloads, one for `const T&` and one for `T&`.

Operators shouldn't be member functions, but that's pretty minor, and I wouldn't really care too much. However, if you do make them member functions, they should definitely be `const`:

```
bool operator!=(const linked_list &other) const
                                        //^^^^^
```

All in all, there is a lot lacking for an implementation, even given the short time span. The lack of any kind of dynamic memory allocation would probably be a deal-breaker for me personally. Without being able to hear your reasoning about this, I'd make the assumption that you didn't understand allocations or object lifetimes, which is of critical importance when programming in C++.

**Edit**: If given a limited time (such as one hour) to write something like a `list`, I'd probably approach it in the following way: firstly, sketch out the minimal interface I want to develop from. Given the pretty strict time requirements, I'd keep it as simple as possible:

1. A private internal `node` struct with all public members (this cuts down on boilerplate code that needs to be written, and since it's private, it's not user facing, so I'd argue it's fine anyway).
2. Private members for `list`, which I'd keep to a `node *head` and `std::size_t size`.
3. Basic constructors, copy assignment, copy constructor, destructor.
4. Insert, update and delete. Since this is a singly linked list, insert would be limited to adding something to the front (`push_front` if we're following standard lib naming), something to update a given value, and something to delete a given value. Usually these would use iterators, but that's too complex given the tight time restrictions.
5. Something to get the size, if the list is empty, and maybe some basic comparison operators.

Sketching out this API, I'd have something like:

```
template <typename T>
class linked_list
{
private:

    struct node
    {
        T data_;
        node* next_;

        node(const T& data)
          : data_(data),
            next(nullptr)
        { }
    };

    std::size_t size_;
    node* head_;

public:

    linked_list()
      : head_(nullptr),
        size_(0)
    { }

    linked_list(const T& data)
      : head(new node(data)),
        size_(1)
    { }

    ~linked_list() { }
    linked_list(const linked_list& rhs) { }
    linked_list& operator=(linked_list rhs) { } //Use copy-swap idiom

    bool is_empty() const { }
    std::size_t size() const  { }

    void push_front(const T& value) { }
    bool remove(const T& value) { }
    bool update(const T& value) { }  

    void swap(linked_list& rhs) { }
};

template <typename T>
void swap(linked_list<T>& lhs, linked_list<T>& rhs) { }

template <typename T>
bool operator<(const linked_list<T>& lhs, const linked_list<T>& rhs) { }

template <typename T>
bool operator>(const linked_list<T>& lhs, const linked_list<T>& rhs) { }

template <typename T>
bool operator==(const linked_list<T>& lhs, const linked_list<T>& rhs) { }

template <typename T>
bool operator!=(const linked_list<T>& lhs, const linked_list<T>& rhs) { }
```

I'd then start to fill in functions as I went - some of them are one-liners (`is_empty` and `size`), some of them take a bit more work. I'd pay the most attention to getting the destructor and copy constructor right, since these are probably the functions that would be scrutinized the most. Even if this API is slightly ambitious, and if some of the functions don't end up being implemented, at least it shows *intent*.

Finally, after the hour was up, I'd want to be ready to discuss what this implementation is lacking compared to say, the standard library `list`: from memory, `Allocator` template parameter, `iterator` + `const_iterator`, `typedef`s such as `value_type`, `reference_type`, functions such as `remove_if`, `sort`, `unique` and so on (although this is probably getting to in-depth - unless you've been working with the standard library a lot and know it very well, this is probably too much detail - but it might be worth it to know at least a little bit about `std::list`).

Given the incredibly limited time, I'd likely eschew unit testing. In fact, unless I had a compiler, I'd be almost positive there would be at least a few errors lurking around - syntax or otherwise. This wouldn't bother me - few people can sit down and bang out even a simplified container class without making a single mistake. To me, it is the high level overview that is important, along with those few key functions (destructor, copy constructor).

Comment: Thanks for the feed back. This was a timed practice run of mine, and your comments make me happy that this was not the actual interview. But apparently I have a lot of work to do. If you were to be asked this question where would you start? Would you list out all the functionality, then implement it? Or would you do one thing at a time and demonstrate that you can unit test things one step at a time?

Comment: @MatthewHoggan I've updated my post re your question, since it's a bit too much for a comment.

Comment: I greatly appreciate you taking your time in answering my question. It is this kind of help that hopefully will bring more skilled c++ developers into this world.